# npm giving error on Mac Big Sur, not able to install or run

Tags: node.js, npm

I just installed node with the below commands and here are the outputs

$ brew install node

$ node -v

```
v9.4.0
```

$ command -v node

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/node

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 icyborg  wheel  35697312 Jan 14  2018 /usr/local/bin/node
```

after running

$ brew upgrade node

Warning: node 15.9.0 already installed

but when I do

$ node -v
v9.4.0

now when I am trying to do

```
npm -v
```

It gives this error,

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `stat` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/node-gyp/lib/index.js:2:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/lib/run-script-pkg.js:4:55)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:163
      throw new Error('call config.load() before reading values')
      ^
```

It is difficult to understand this error. May I know what can be the issue? I thought npm comes with node and I can't find any way to install it independently on mac.

**SOLUTION** - it seems node wasn't LinkedIn. I ran

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

and it is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js 9 has been unsupported for about 3 years. The error you're seeing is very likely due to using an old Node.js with a new npm.

When I run `brew info node`, it says 15.2.0 is available. So, either something went wrong with your `brew` installation, or else you have an old version of Node.js somewhere else in your path (or as an alias) that runs instead of the version installed by `brew`.

Run `command -v node` to find out what Node.js is being executed. If it doesn't start with `/usr/local/bin/node`, then that's your problem. If it is `/usr/local/bin/node`, run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/node` to make sure it's a link to something in `/usr/local/Cellar/node`. If it's not, that's your problem... (EDIT #2: ...and as OP notes in a comment, `brew link --overwrite node` fixed that for them. So anyone else reading this can try that.)

EDIT #1: Since you've updated the question with the above information: It looks like you probably installed Node.js 9 around 3 years ago with the regular installer and not `brew`. Again, you can probably avoid all these headaches by uninstalling with brew and reinstalling with `nvm` as mentioned in the next paragraph.

In general, if you're installing Node.js on a personal computer and not on a server, I'd recommend uninstalling the `brew` version and installing with a per-user version manager.  [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script) is a solid choice:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the output.

Comment: It looks like you probably installed Node.js 9 around 3 years ago with the regular installer and not brew. Again, you can probably avoid all these headaches by uninstalling with brew and reinstalling with nvm as mentioned in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I ran brew link --overwrite node and it solved the issue. now node -v is showing 15 and npm is also working.

Comment: Ah, cool, I'll add that to the answer so anyone else showing up here finds it easily.